# How to change django-allauth google redirect domain?

Tags: django, nginx, google-api, gunicorn, django-allauth

If I try to login using google provider, I get redirected to

```
http://127.0.0.1:8001/accounts/google/login/callback/...
```

whereas I should be redirected to

```
http://example.com/accounts/google/login/callback/...
```

How can I fix that?

**Update:**

According to my server configuration `127.0.0.1:8001` is where the gunicorn_django runs and the port 80 is handled by nginx.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably this is the URL configured in your google app. Check Google Developers Console and make sure that your callback URL is correct..